# How can I implement a security trimmed Html.RenderAction?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am looking to create a security trimmed (basically if you don't have permission don't render) Html.RenderAction.

The aim is to display various widgets/page components and if the person doesn't have permission on the action the RenderAction doesn't get called (or at least doesn't cause a re-direct to login page). For example the page is shown to all logged in users. However there will be parts that are only for HR, Business Development and if you are in HR and Business development you would get both parts etc.

Each part called by RenderAction is stand-alone so it means I can easily make pages that contain all the required parts but then they just don't display if the user isn't permitted. If I call RenderAction on for an action someone doesn't have permission to then it causes them to get re-directed to login page.

I have seen something similar done with links but as anyone done anything similar for Actions?

I was hoping to get something like:

```
@Html.RenderSecurityTrimmedAction("Main","Business-Widget1")
@Html.RenderSecurityTrimmedAction("Main","HR-Widget")
@Html.RenderSecurityTrimmedAction("Main","General-Widget3")
```

Where Widget access is based on the persons current role. I have security access working perfectly. It's mainly creating a RenderAction that doesn't uncenssarily run the Action if the user doesn't have perission

I want to keep the code DRY so I don't want to be carrying lots of ViewModel properties and then having to wrap every Html.RenderAction in an if statement. These components will appear in a variety of places so I want  them to be plug and play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented the following:

```
    public static void SecurityTrimmedRenderAction(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
                                                  ActionResult actionResult)
    {
        var routeValueDictionary = actionResult.GetRouteValueDictionary();
        var actionName = (string)routeValueDictionary["Action"];
        var controllerName = (string)routeValueDictionary["Controller"];
        //var areaName = (string)routeValueDictionary["Area"];
        var hasActionPermission = SecurityTrimmingExtensions.HasActionPermission(htmlHelper, actionName,
                                                                                 controllerName);
        if (hasActionPermission)
        {
            htmlHelper.RenderAction(actionResult);
        }
    }
```

The SecurityTrimmingExtensions follows the code found here: [ASP.Net MVC how to determine if a user can access a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196994/asp-net-mvc-how-to-determine-if-a-user-can-access-a-url)

I don't have to touch Authorize doing it this way as the code isn't called if the current user doesn't have permissions

Answer (score 3):

You may try this extension method:

```
public static void CustomRenderAction(this HtmlHelper helper, string actionName)
{
    if (helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
        return;

    helper.RenderAction(actionName);
}
```

If you want to specify roles for each action you may do next thing:

1) override AuthorizeAttribute as follows:

```
public class MyAuthAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
{
  public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
  {
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Items["DontRedirectToLogin"] != null)
    {
       if (base.AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext) == false)
       {
          filterContext.Result = new EmptyResult();
          return;
       }

       return;
    }

    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
  }
}
```

2) change RenderAction:

```
public static void CustomRenderAction(this HtmlHelper helper, string actionName)
{
    helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items["DontRedirectToLogin"] = true

    helper.RenderAction(actionName);
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I meant that they could be Authorized by not have the appropriate role. Should have been cleaerer

Comment: then extend if() with another condition: helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("barbarian")

Comment: Then I have to define the roles in the helper. The roles are decorating the controller action in the Authorize action so I don't want to confifgure them again. Just means maintaing them in two places so isn't DRY. Thanks

Comment: @GraemeMiller, is that any issue if your are following my suggestion. My solution is similar to Dima's one, just did some more logic to store the permission settings

Comment: Thanks for your help. Having looked at edit I still don't think this is what I am looking for. I don't want to set a bypass to authorization. I want to check the User is authorized based on their permission to do the the action being called, and then RenderAction on that basis. Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121000/stuck-creating-a-security-trimmed-html-actionlink-extension-method but for RenderAction

Comment: Overriding the attributes is a good thing, but it will redirect to login page or an error page, if the IsAuthorized is false. This will prevent if the user clicks on the button, he doesn't have the privileage. But if you are using my solution, it prevents displaying  the control. I think he requires hiding the parts of the page.

Comment: These are totally self contained Widgets so there will be no button etc just the widget as whole. I either want to show them if the user has permission to access the action that generates them or not. I want to base the decision to execute the RenderAction entirely on whether they have permission to execute it based on the attributes on the action.

Comment: @GraemeMiller, have update the code above, so it should check for roles either.

Answer (score 1):

**There are multiple user type and permission or access is varies from one user type to another.**

This is what I got from your question. Based on the permission, you need to show or hide the components. The components can be of grids, button, text box, messages etc. in a page.
Or A view is rendered differently based on the logged in user (his permission).

This can be easily implemented using an HTML Helper.

A rough Idea.

You need to store the data in xml,database etc. ie, you need to map the logged in user type with Controllers and Actions.

**Table/Data Permission Settings**

```
Admin - UserController- ViewAllUsersAction
Admin-  UserController- DeleteUserAction
Employee - UserController- RequestUserAccessAction
Employee - AlertsController- LatestNewsAction
* - UsersController- ChangePasswordAction
```

Consider two user types . Admin, Employee. Admin is having access to ViewAllUsers,DeleteUser etc. Employee is having access to ReqUserAccess,LatestNewsAction.

**HtmlHelper**

```
public static bool IsAuthorized(this HtmlHelper helper, string Controller, string Action)
{ 
   // This method query the database/storage withe controller,action and usertype.
   // In case of WindowsAuthentication, you can get the userGroup from a LDAP Server/Domain. You must know the logged in user group here, if you are not using win auth.
}
```

**In EmpList.Cshtml**

```
if( @Html.IsAuthorized("UserController","DeleteUserAction"))   <input type="submit" text="Delete Employee" />
```

So if the user type is Admin, then it will return true else, false, so that part is not executed and not displayed.

In case of Windows authentication, we need to use Windows User Group instead of usertype mentioned above.

**Edit**

```
if( @Html.IsAuthorized("Main","HR-Widget"))
   @Html.RenderSecurityTrimmedAction("Main","HR-Widget") 
   // this will be rendered only based on the permission for the user.
```

Thanks, Hope this is useful for you. :)

Comment: Just wondering how I would detect whether the Action call in IsAuthorized is returning successfully do I need to look at the response code?

Comment: @GraemeMiller We need to check the particular group or role is allowed to perform the action . It can be stored in database,xml etc. If it is allowed then the action button is visible, else it won't . Similarly he can hide the div, Partial views,Render Actions etc. I implemented this one personally

Comment: I will have decorated my controller action with who has permissions to access it. That is my issue. I can easily just test in code and duplicate my permission code. My problem is that I want to base the decision on whether they can access the action method so that the code only relies on the security requirements of the Action

Comment: Based on your question `there will be parts that are only for HR, Business Development and if you are in HR and Business development you would get both parts etc.` You need to hide or show some parts based on the logged in user type. This will be handled in `View`. So the best way to show or hide is using Html Helpers in View.

Answer (score 0):

I found the set of extension methods here work best: http://vivien-chevallier.com/Articles/create-an-authorized-action-link-extension-for-aspnet-mvc-3

It actually executes all the ActionFilters on the action you specify so you don't have to execute it yourself.

The only downside is that it doesn't support areas the way it is written. I'm sure it could be modified to also understand areas.