# Restricting Some parts of the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an organization. In that organization you can have multiple roles. (Lets take only two of them for now), **Nurse** and **Admin**.

So I have 'protected' my controller actions like this

```
[AuthorizeUser(UserRole = "Admin, Nurse", OrganizationType = "Institution")]
```

My AuthorizeUser class is like this

```
public class AuthorizeUser : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public String UserRole { get; set; }



    public string OrganizationType { get; set; }
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!isAuthorized)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return CheckOrganizationType.checkRole(this.UserRole, this.OrganizationType, Auth.CurrentUser);
    }
}
```

The function CheckOrganiztionType is like this

```
public static bool checkRole(String role, String organizationType, User user)
    {
        RolesType rt = null;
        OrganizationType ot = null;
        foreach (UserRoles ur in user.GetUserRoles())
        {
            rt = RolesType.Get(ur.organizationTypeId,ur.roleTypeId);
            ot = OrganizationType.Get(ur.organizationTypeId, "1");



        }

        if (rt != null && role.Contains(rt.Name) && ot != null && ot.Name == organizationType)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

It works perfectly. If I am not an admin or not a Nurse I am not allowed to go here.

But what I would like to do also is to control some parts of my view using the same technique. After searching on the internet I found something which I am going to post below and I would you people to comment on that.

In my cshtml file I do this

```
@using InstaFood.Helpers
@using InstaFood.Secuirty

@if (CheckOrganizationType.checkRole("Admin", "Institution", Auth.CurrentUser))
{
   <span>Admin</span>
}else{
   <span>Nurse</span>
}
```

Do you think it is the right approach or is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Seems like a sensible enough approach.  If conditional checks work in some server-side code, they'd work in other server-side code.  As long as the security checks are done server-side and not client-side, you're likely fine.  Whether or not this scales in terms of maintainability is something time will tell.  You may find at some later point that you'd rather just create separate views and conditionally return the right view from the controller.  There are pros and cons either way, so it depends on what's easier to maintain in your specific codebase.

Comment: This is a not bad solution: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13470761/1207195

Comment: Can the down voter explain the reason for down voting it?

Answer (score 1):

If you implement a custom RoleProvider, where u provide roles for user based on your domain model, 
then in your views you can use code like this:

```
if (User.IsInRole("Admin")) {
     <span>Admin</span>
}
else {
    ....
}
```

custom RoleProvider can be found in here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/317sza4k(v=vs.100).aspx

to register you custom roleprovider you must configure web.config at configuration/system.web/roleManager

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="OdbcRoleProvider" 
  enabled="true"
  cacheRolesInCookie="true"
  cookieName=".ASPROLES"
  cookieTimeout="30"
  cookiePath="/"
  cookieRequireSSL="false"
  cookieSlidingExpiration="true"
  cookieProtection="All" >
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add
      name="OdbcRoleProvider"
      type="Samples.AspNet.Roles.OdbcRoleProvider"
      connectionStringName="OdbcServices" 
      applicationName="SampleApplication" 
      writeExceptionsToEventLog="false" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: Any example on how to do custom role provider?

Comment: just added more info